# How to rotate a 2D Scatter Plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, rotation, scatter-plot

I have created a 2D scatter plot with the following commands:

```
h = scatter(handles.axsScatterPlot, sig2, sig1, 'x');
xlabel(['Signal ' num2str(sigNum2) ' Amplitude']);
ylabel(['Signal ' num2str(sigNum1) ' Amplitude']);
```

I need to rotate the scatter plot by 90 degress clockwise.

Using `camroll(90)` works, but the axes labels get all messed up.

I have tried using `rotate(h, [0 0 1], 90);` and `rotate(handles.axsScatterPlot, [0 0 1], 90);` but neither one seems to have any effect.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***[view](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/view.html)*** or the ***[camva](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/camva.html)*** commands can specify your viewing angle.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of that. I managed to do it using `view(90, 90)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use camporbit(theta, phi) instead of camproll(theta)